# Dropping the Unicode markers in Html output

Tags: python, html, django, unicode, html-lists

I have a python list which holds a few email ids accepted as unicode strings:

```
[u'one@example.com',u'two@example.com',u'three@example.com']
```

This is assigned to `values['Emails']` and `values` is passed to render as html.
The Html renders as this:

> Emails: [u'one@example.com',u'two@example.com',u'three@example.com']

I would like it to look like this:

> Emails: [ one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com ]

How can I do this in the server script?
Is there a simple way to achieve this in the HTML itself?

Comment: Thank you very much all my friends for trying to suggest the solutions.
What really worked for my solution on the client side is as follows. 
[&nbsp;{% for email in Emails %} {{ email | escape }}&nbsp;{% endfor %}&nbsp;]

Special thanks to anteatersa !
Warm regards.

Comment: Good it works, but in your solution, where's the comma you requested between the addresses? Furthermore, I wouldn't call this "client side". This Python code still runs on the server, right? (Please, accept an answer to indicate it's solved.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way for you to do it would be to iterate over your email list. e.g.

```
{% for email in Emails %}
email,
{% endfor %}
```

This way you (or a designer) will have a lot more control of the layout.

Have a look at the [template documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#topics-templates) for more details.

Comment: That would surely give you one excessive comma in the output?

Comment: Thank you. This client side solution works with the following modifications.
{% for email in Emails %}
{{ email|escape}}
{% endfor %}

Comment: In the question he says he would like a comma between the email addresses.

Comment: Dear anteatresa,  The crux of the problem was to drop the unicode indicator and if possible solving it on the html itself. Adding a comma in between was a nice-to-have. I can work a little more on that and achieve the same. In the above stated improved solution on your suggestion is using &nbsp; so that the simple for-loop will not give me the comma after the last list item. Thanks once more !

Comment: @anteatersa, but wouldn't your solution *also* print that comma *after* the last address? @Sharma Anil, I feel using `join` to get commas *between* the email addresses (but not after the last one) really was an easier solution. (And in my opinion anything is much better than using `&nbsp;` -- just consider what will happen if the number of addresses is too long to fit on a single line in the browser.)

Comment: @Arjan, please read the added comment on Jim Robert's suggestion to use join:", " - regards.

Answer (score 4):

In Python:

```
'[%s]' % ', '.join(pythonlistwithemails)
```

In bare HTML it is impossible... you'd have to use javascript.

Comment: I'd say: trying this in HTML or JavaScript is simply not recommended, unless the string that represents the whole list is documented to actually look like that in all versions of Python...?

Comment: Actually, using this string format idiom leaves you with a long *unicode* string: `u'one@example.com,two@example.com,three@example.com'`. - Not exaclty what the OP wanted.

Comment: @ThomasH, so is that concatenated string in your comment above also **printed** including the `u'..'` "debug" info? I don't know any Python, but as in your own answer `str()` is said to be invoked implicitly, then why not in liori's answer?

Comment: Well, I guess the OP implicitly calls repr. Then... well, the OP probably should change that.

Comment: you can just use the join filter in a django template... actually I'll just add it as an answer ;)

Comment: @Arjan Actually, I was probably mislead by the Python interactive shell. The **types** of *str(u'one@example.com')* (<type 'str'>) and *'%s' % u'one@example.com'* (type 'unicode') are different, and the shell shows this. But if you actually **print** those two expression you get the same output. And your argument is right, since the format string '%s' asks for the str() representation of the argument, which speak for the implicit application of str(). Don't know why this is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any Python, but if those `u`-markers and the single quotes show, doesn't that actually indicate that you're accessing the list members in the wrong way?

You're printing the whole list rather than each item, and the output looks like debug information to me. Such debug information could very well look different in another version or configuration of Python. So, though I don't know Python, I'd say: you should NOT try to parse that.

Using [liori's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222508/dropping-the-unicode-markers/1222524#1222524) does not actually *drop* the `u`-markers, but ensures the items from the list are accessed individually, which gives you the true value rather than some debug information. You could also use some loop to achieve the same (though the `join` makes the code a lot easier).

Comment: *"u'...'" * is a print representation of a Python unicode string. It simply inidcates that the underlying strings are unicode strings (which is good), and that you have to take care once you serialize them (to a file, to the screen, to a byte-string representation, etc.). I aggree with you, the list is not the important thing here, it's the individual strings which should be taken care of, as I outlined in my <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222508/dropping-the-unicode-markers/1222595#1222595">answer</a>.

Answer (score 2):

```
"[{0}]".format(", ".join(python_email_list))
```

From Python 2.6 format() method is the preferred way of string formatting.
Docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html).

Answer (score 1):

It all depends how the HTML generation is treating your *values* array. Here is what you usually do to serialize a unicode string:

```
In [550]: ss=u'one@example.com'

In [551]: print ss   # uses str() implicitly
Out[552]: one@example.com

In [552]: str(ss)
Out[552]: 'one@example.com'

In [553]: repr(ss)
Out[553]: "u'one@example.com'"
```

If you are confident *values* only contains ASCII character strings, just use *str()* on the values. If you are unsure, use an explicit encoding like

```
ss.encode('ascii', error='replace')
```

Answer (score 1):

In the template

```
[ {{ email_list|join:", " }} ]
```

note: the [, and ] are literal square brackets, not code :)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
myStr = str('[ ' + ', '.join(ss) + ' ]')
```

Option 2:

```
myStr = '[ ' + ', '.join(ss) + ' ]'
myStr = myStr.encode(<whatever encoding you want>, <whatever way of handling errors you wish to use>)
```

I'm not used to Python pre-version 3, so I'm not really sure whether the additional strings need a `u` prefix or if it's an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a long and formatted comment on [the last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222508/dropping-the-unicode-markers-in-html-output/1237495#1237495). Still not knowing any Python, I am a bit disappointed by not using `join` to get commas between each address (like [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222508/dropping-the-unicode-markers-in-html-output/1222524#1222524) by liori). Replacing the comma with some space feels like walking away from the problem, and is not going to learn anyone anything. We don't sacrifice quality here at Stack Overflow! ;-)

I just typed the following on my Mac:

```
$ python
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Feb  6 2009, 19:02:12) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> lst = [ u'one@example.com', u'two@example.com', u'three@example.com' ]
>>> print lst
[u'one@example.com', u'two@example.com', u'three@example.com']

>>> print ', '.join(lst)
one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com

>>> print 'Emails: [%s]' % ', '.join(lst)
Emails: [one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com]

>>> lst = [ u'one@example.com' ]
>>> print lst
[u'one@example.com']

>>> print ', '.join(lst)
one@example.com

>>> print 'Emails: [%s]' % ', '.join(lst)
Emails: [one@example.com]

>>> s = u'one@example.com'
>>> print s
one@example.com

>>> print ', '.join(s)
o, n, e, @, e, x, a, m, p, l, e, ., c, o, m
```

Makes perfect sense to me... Now, using a different separator for the last item ([like](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2008-July/670406.html) *one@example.com, two@example.com **and** three@example.com*) will need some more work, but printing the very same separator between each item should not be complicated at all.